# Como criar todas as possibilidades de um esquema com um laço?

Tags: php, javascript, java

Por exemplo, fazer que A, B, e C troquem de lugar uns com outros, e depois definir quantas e todas as trocas. ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA, etc.
Quero fazer isso com o laço for e prefiro Javascript, mas não é necessário ser nela, pode ser em PHP, C++, Java, etc.

OBS: O que eu quero criar é um quadro de RGB. Ou seja tem que ter 3 variáveis, de 0 à 255.

Comment: A, B e C são inteiros? Serão sempre três elementos? Se sim, qual seria o problema em simplesmente sempre retornar uma lista fixa com ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB e CBA?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617055/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: Obrigado Daniel